# Show only the future event (Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, events

I’m trying to make event ticker with Advanced Custom Fields and I want to show only events that are happening on the current day or in the future. But I don’t know how to hide past events. Could anyone help me, please?

This is my code. It works fine, but it doesn't hide past events.

```
<?php $event = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'           => 'gacr-event',
  'posts_per_page'  => 5,
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'               => 'DESC'
)); ?>

<?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('date')); ?>

<?php while($event->have_posts()) : $event->the_post(); ?>  
    <li>   
        Posted on: <?php the_field('date'); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query). There's also [documentation on ACF for querying dates](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/#template-usage).

```
<?php

$event = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'       => 'gacr-event',
        'posts_per_page'  => 5,
        'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'      => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'date',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC', // MySQL needs to treat date meta values as numbers
                'value' => current_time( 'Ymd' ), // Today in ACF datetime format
                'compare' => '>=', // Greater than or equal to value
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Aaaa, such a simple thing and I couldn't figure out how.
Thank you so much, you are my hero. It works now!